# Context menu fails to display

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, android-sqlite

In my code, I want to add a context menu. I have a list coming from my database. I have a table named *MONEY* which has four fields: *ID*, *FIRSTNAME*, *MONEY*, and *DESCRIPTION*. My list view is working fine, but the context menu is not working. The problem is in the `onContextItemSelected()` method. It does not show context menu when i long press in list item.

### contextmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/Delete"
    android:title="Delete"/>

</Menu>
```

### Money.java

```
package com.anurag.main;

public class Money extends Activity {
ArrayList list1, list2, list3, list4;
TextView text1, text2, text3, text4;
ImageView iv;
ListView mList;
SQLiteDatabase db;
private static String DBNAME = "MainDB.db";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.money);
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mList);
    list1 = new ArrayList();
    list2 = new ArrayList();
    list3 = new ArrayList();
    list4 = new ArrayList();
    try {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from MONEY", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            list1.add(c.getString(1));
            list2.add(c.getString(3));
            list3.add(c.getString(5));
            list4.add(c.getString(4));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
//Problem in this code 
    mList.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

    mList.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextmenu, menu);

        }
    });

    //end here
}
//problem in this code
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item 
            .getMenuInfo(); 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Delete:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    default:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
//End Here
class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return 0;
        return list1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom1, null);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom1, null);
        text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        // text1.setText(list1[position]);
        text1.setText(list1.get(position).toString());
        text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text2.setText(list2.get(position).toString());
        text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        text3.setText(list3.get(position).toString());
        text4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text4);
        text4.setText(list4.get(position).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: When you say that it's not working, what's not working? Does it fail to display the menu you expect to see? Does it display it correctly, but it doesn't do anything when you select a menu item?

Comment: It does not display menu @Blumer

Comment: When i long press in list item then my application show error. i can see in logcat @Blumer

Comment: What is the error that displays in the logcat?

Comment: at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:113)
  at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:80)

Comment: 10-10 23:02:52.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18752):  at com.anurag.main.Money$1.onCreateContextMenu(Money.java:65)
10-10 23:02:52.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18752):  at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:4362)
10-10 23:02:52.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18752):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:81)
10-10 23:02:52.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18752):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:1880)

Comment: are you working on it @Blumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *bet* that the error is that in parsing the .xml file, it was "Expecting menu, got Menu". De-capitalize `<Menu></Menu>` in `contextmenu.xml` and see if that resolves it.

Comment: It cant be capitalize @Blumer

Comment: It is not allowed to be capitalized, no. Your XML in your question shows that it is. Make it lowercase: "menu" instead of "Menu".

Comment: If i capitalize then this line <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu> automatically added in the bottom of the xml file

Comment: I've run into that, too--there's something goofy going on with the Android Common XML Editor. Close the file. In the File Explorer window, right-click on the file, select *Open With*, and select *XML Editor*. Then change the tag to lower case.

Comment: Thank you very much @Blumer my xml file shows it in lower case but in actual it was in upper case now i have deleted my xml file and created a new file and i finally got the menu. Thanks again